# iOS - How long does NSManagedObject stay allocated without saving

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Here is the scenario in my app: I download data from a JSON File which I stock in Coredata WITHOUT saving it. If the users wants to keep the data, he clicks on a button, and I save the context. 
My question is: if the user doesn't click on the button and I don't save the data, how long will the Context stay the way it is? Until the user closes the app? Or even goes to background?

I'm looking for the best way to manage it.

Comment: depends... can the user make any other changes to anything before deciding about saving?

Comment: No the user cannot change the data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do nothing to change it and that the app receives no memory warnings, doesn't crash and doesn't go to the background - indefinitely. If the app goes to the background it may be killed at any time if the OS requires it, so you can rely on nothing.

Really you should save the context as soon as possible. If you need to, save to a different store file on disk, then if the user discards you can delete that file and if they save you can move it to replace the original file (or just update a config which says where the current valid file is located on disk).

Comment: Actually the point is that I would only like to save it if the user really wants to download the data. Otherwise I'd like to use CoreData as a temporary stocking place. I know it's not the best method but it's to avoid having to implement two completely different methods for the people that want to downlod the data and for the people who don't. Am I being clear...? How should I do this?

Comment: Just save to a cache directory instead of a main directory then?

Comment: Aaaaaah that is a great solution. How do you do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Find it with NSCachesDirectory, just like you would for the documents directory

Comment: Thanks ! Final question: with the Cache directory, it will only be deleted in case of low memory. There is no way to delete whenever the app is closed or anything like that?

Comment: You can delete it manually, or delete just before you save a new file to that location. You don't need to worry about it too much so long as you don't load the wrong one...